# matplotlib bar graph black - how do I remove bar borders

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, border

I'm using pyplot.bar but I'm plotting so many points that the color of the bars is always black.  This is because the borders of the bars are black and there are so many of them that they are all squished together so that all you see is the borders (black).  Is there a way to remove the bar borders so that I can see the intended color?

Comment: Read the docstring for `bar`.  It says right there that setting `linewidth=0` means don't draw edges.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Set the `edgecolor` to `"none"`: `bar(..., edgecolor = "none")`

Comment: Whereas plural `edgecolors` works for scatterplots, only singular `edgecolor` works for bar graphs.

Comment: Both `linewidth=0` and `edgecolor='none'` works also in `stackplot` :-)

Comment: `linewidth=0` is nicer because it lets you keep hatching.

Answer (score 21):

Another option is to set `edgecolor` to be the intended color in your call to `bar`:

```
# If your intended color is blue, this will work:
bar(. . . , edgecolor='b')
```